# How to use class variables inside methods that contain functions?

Tags: javascript, oop

So lets say I have this code:

```
MyClass = {

    classVar1: 'Teddy Bear',
    classVar2: 'Boogy Man',

    firstMethod: function() {
        console.log('I love my' + this.classVar1); // works

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('But I hate the ' + this.classVar2); // does not work
        }, 2000);

        someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('I also hate the ' + this.classVar2); // also does not work
        });

    }

};

MyClass.firstMethod();
```

Because there is a nested function inside of `firstMethod` I cannot access the second class variable. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've created here is a javascript object and not a class. In order to create a class you would need to do something like this:

```
var MyClass = function() {

    var self = this; // Create a local variable that stores a pointer to 'this'

    this.classVar1 = 'Teddy Bear';
    this.classVar2 = 'Boogy Man';

    this.firstMethod = function() {
        console.log('I love my' + self.classVar1); // use self instead of this

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('But I hate the ' + self.classVar2); // use self instead of this
        }, 2000);

        someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('I also hate the ' + self.classVar2); // use self instead of this
        });
    }
};
```

And then use the above class to create an object like this:

```
var myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.firstMethod();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the line `console.log('I love my' + self.classVar1);`, could it also be `console.log('I love my' + this.classVar1);` because it is not inside a function?

Comment: The idea is to avoid any ambiguity in what exactly 'this' refers to, as it will always point to the current object depending on the run-time context. So, I prefer using self always. Having said that, I'd recommend you give it a try and see if it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to force the `this` value to be correct:

```
setTimeout((function() {
    console.log('But I hate the ' + this.classVar2);
}).bind(this), 2000);
```

Alternatively, you can just capture the original `this` value in a variable:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('But I hate the ' + that.classVar2);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store reference to parent `this`;

```
firstMethod: function() {
    var _this = this;
    console.log('I love my' + this.classVar1);

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('But I hate the ' + _this.classVar2); 
    }, 2000);

    someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('I also hate the ' + _this.classVar2);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To refer to your variable within your own class you simply have to

```
Class={
     classvar:'x'
     function myfunction(){
           return this.classvar;
     }
 }
 Class.myfunction(); // should return x
```

should be enough this.variable to access a global variable in a method within a class or an object